# restart service in case of exception

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I'm developing service application that must restart itself. What are the ways of doing that? Is it possible to ask system start application again if it is stopped? I'm using Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your service can programably configure recovery options for itself by calling the Win32 API [`ChangeServiceConfig2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988.aspx) function inside of its `AfterInstall` event.  Set the `dwInfoLevel` to `SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS` and set the `lpInfo` to point at a `SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS` record describing what you want to happen when the service fails.

Answer (score 6):

If you go into `services.msc` you can configure this for you service. You don't have to do it in code. See the Recovery tab when you open the properties of you service.

Comment: +1, interesting. Is there a known way how to configure this recovery programatically (somewhere in registry I suppose) ?

Comment: You probably could by going into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services`. Probably a better alternative would be to add a `InstallerClass` to your service and configure it from code there.

Comment: The Delphi service module has options to configure this too, at least in later versions.

Comment: @mj2008 Don't know anything about that :) BTW. The `InstallerClass` is a .net thing. Although Delphi probably has something similair, the `InstallerClass` is .net specific. My mistake!